# Download large files using REST API and browser's download manager

Tags: angular, azure, rest, download, blob

We are facing small problem in our Angular frontend application - our client want to download reports. Once report is generated we are using GET endpoint which haves crucial headers, such as `access-control-expose-headers: content-disposition` and `content-disposition: attachment; filename=TasksReport-28-10-2022.xlsx; filename*=UTF-8''Report.xlsx`. That part works properly, the file is being downloaded. The problem starts when file is bigger (~150MB) and we have to wait for response. I am using busy indicator for that, but client wants to have downloading like "regular file" - so wants to see full progress in browser's download manager.

So now we have "long" request after which file is being immediately saved on HDD:
[image]

[image]

But we want to achieve something similar to just pressing direct file download link:
[image]

[image]

We were thinking to just provide direct URI to file, but I don't think this is the best way, right?
How can we setup API or UI to achieve this?
Thank you for any help, if more info is required, I'd be happy to edit the question and provide it.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive to the follow way:

1. Your files will be packed.
2. Google sends a response with the packed filename (like: .com/a8jek8-djfl8-dfle-fj393f)
3. Client (Browser-App) call the link and the browser download starts.
   Like this:

```
  downloadURI(uri: string, name: string) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'name';
    link.href = uri;
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    link.click();
    link.remove();
  }
```

**Second way**:
You can use the `reportProgress` option inside your get request

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(environment.backendUrl + '/your-path', {
        observe: 'events',
        reportProgress: true,
      })
...
```

So you can build your one download progress window and so on.

Greetings, Florian